# Как рассчитать IP подсетей в сети класса B?

Tags: ip

Есть сеть класса B, её нужно разделить на 100 подсетей →
на адреса подсетей выделяем 7 бит, 9 бит остаётся на адреса хостов в подсетях →
всего в подсети может быть 510 адресов (за вычетом адреса сети и широковещательного) и насколько я понял октет IP не может быть больше 255, тогда как дать свой адрес каждому хосту?
Если 3й октет IP будет меняться только с 0 на 1 а 4й от 0 до 255 то получится только 508 IP, опять таки за вычетом адреса сети и широковещательного.

Comment: https://www.site24x7.com/tools/ipv4-subnetcalculator.html

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk я не понимаю как при разделении сети класса B на 128 подсетей получается 17 бит на адреса хостов в подсети, откуда вообще 17 взялось?

Comment: 128 подсетей и 512 адресов -> 16 бит. Откуда 17? И в 9 бит можно записать число от 0 до 511 -> итого 510 реальных адресов. Откуда 508?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja просто я по ссылке 1го комменария прошёл, указал IP и 128 подсетей, а он мне выдал что в подсети будет 2^17 хостов.  
Там ещё после IP через слеш по умолчанию стоит 8, если поставить 16 то всё правильно считает, что значит это число после слеша у IP?

Comment: Так там А-сеть по дефолту, для нее все правильно: 8 + 7 + 17 = 32. Если зададите В-сеть 192.168.0.0/16  будет все как вам надо.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja зачем указывать количество бит через слеш  в IP если для этого есть маска?

Comment: Это не IP, это описание блока адресов. Как пример: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81#%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0_IPv4